# Можно ли менять цвет кластера яндекс карты в зависимости от количества элементов в кластере?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Можно ли менять цвет кластера Яндекс карты в зависимости от количества элементов в кластере, например, от 1 до 10 цвет синий, от 10 - 100 - жёлтый от 100 до 1000 -красный?

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой, очень простой путь задать свои иконки для каждого размера
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_custom_icon